# A sufficient condition for factorization in a complete local ring

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I think something like the following statement is true, but I don't recall a reference.

Suppose $f(x,y)\in k[[x,y]]$ is power series with no constant or linear terms. Then, if the quadratic terms factor into a product of linear terms, the entire power series factors.

I know I'm missing a condition, because $y^2-x^3$ is a counterexample. But when the quadratic term isn't a square, I believe it's correct. What is the precise statement here?

More generally, what can we say about factorization of power series in power series rings with many variables if we know the lowest degree terms factor?

Comment: You're on the right track. Each distinct factor of the leading term corresponds to a branch, which gives its own factor in the completion. In your case, without loss of generality the leading term is $xy$; then write $f=xy+f_1x+f_2y = (x+f_2)(y+f_1)+\text{something of degree }\ge 4 = \dots$; you get Cauchy sequences in the factors, the product of whose limits must be $f$.